# Why is output printed twice?

Tags: arrays, c, if-statement

I'm making a code for displaying messages from the serial monitor on the LCD display with Arduino. The display is HX1230 and it has 96 by 68 pixels. I've already done displaying text but I want my message to fit in
boxes with the exact size of messages. I want to count each character and add different length to the box.
Example:
"------"
|Hello |
"------"
Im so close but yet so far.
This part of the code is doubled for loop for comparing characters to count the length of the box and I don't understand this: When I use two or more "if" statements to check the characters, why does my code find more than one match?
When I add `break;` to each "if" statement it works perfectly.
But I want to know what is the reason for this ?

```c
char ThreePixel [] = "!.:";
char FourPixel[] = ",;";
char FivePixel[] = "'()[],";
char SixPixel[] = "{|}~*";
char SevenPixel[] = "$%+-012356789<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLNOPQRSTUVXYZ^abcdefghijklnopqrstuvxyz!#&'(+-./01";
char EightPixel[] = "#&*/4MW_`mwĂ„â€žĂ„â€¦";
char Input[] = "Hello[";
int i=0;
int y=0;
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
for(y=0;y<81;y++){
if(Input[i]==ThreePixel[y]){
printf("%c",Input[i]);

}
if(Input[i]==FourPixel[y]){
printf("%c",Input[i]);

}
if(Input[i]==FivePixel[y]){
printf("%c",Input[i]);

}
if(Input[i]==SixPixel[y]){
printf("%c",Input[i]);

}
if(Input[i]==SevenPixel[y]){
printf("%c",Input[i]);

}
if(Input[i]==EightPixel[y]){
printf("%c",Input[i]);
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code with proper indentation to make it readable.

Comment: `for(y=0;y<81;y++){ if(Input[i]==ThreePixel[y])` Looks like you have buffer overruns all over the place. You are using `y` as an index into the `Pixel` strings. But that is wrong because `y` goes up to 80 and whilst most of the strings are much shorter than that. Overrunning buffers results in Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: I am sure you can make a more [mre] to demonstrate your observation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is quick fix:

```c
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    for(y=0;y<3;y++){
    if(Input[i]==ThreePixel[y]){
    printf("%c",Input[i]);
      }}
    for(y=0;y<2;y++){
    if(Input[i]==FourPixel[y]){
    printf("%c",Input[i]);
      }}
    for(y=0;y<5;y++){
    if(Input[i]==FivePixel[y]){
    printf("%c",Input[i])
      }}
    for(y=0;y<5;y++){
    if(Input[i]==SixPixel[y]){
    printf("%c",Input[i]);
      }}
    for(y=0;y<78;y++){
    if(Input[i]==SevenPixel[y]){
    printf("%c",Input[i]);
      }}
    for(y=0;y<21;y++){
    if(Input[i]==EightPixel[y]){
    printf("%c",Input[i]);
      }}
  }
```